# django - get_or_create() is not saving to sqlite db

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to save multiple objects in a loop.

```
for i in range(0,12):
        some_url = "blabla.com/signnum=" + str(i)
        req = urllib2.Request(astro_url,headers=hdr)
        str_response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        json_str = json.load(str_response)
        with transaction.atomic():
            if i == 0:
                capricorn, cp_created = Capricorn.objects.get_or_create(astro_date=json_str['daily']['data_date'],
                        defaults={
                                  'headline': json_str['daily']['headline'],
                                  'headcontent':json_str['daily']['content'],
                                  'rating':json_str['daily']['rating'],
                                  'love_rate':json_str['daily']['love'],
                        })
                if cp_created:
                    print 'Capricorn saved'
                else:
                    print 'Capricorn is already in db'
            if i == 1:
                #different model
            if i == 2:
                #different model
            ....
            ....
```

and this goes on till 12. the same fields only different model names.

the problem i am having is that the last 12th object is not being inserted into db, although

```
if last_created:
     print last_createdobj.id
     print 'LastModelObject saved'
else:
     print 'LastModelObject is already in db'
```

is printing `1` and `LastModelObject saved`. all other objects are being inserted.

what is happenning here? the loop is really looping 12 times. and writing into db is happenning atomic. what can go bad here? I am really stuck..

i am using sqlite (dev) and it is printing the id `1` which doesnot exist in db, what the heck?

Comment: Assuming the logic behind the check `if i==0:` is right, does the function print `Capricorn saved` or `already in db` ? and how are you computing the `last_created` object?

Comment: @karthikr yes, capricorn is just the first model which is being saved successfully, the 12th model which is ``i==11`` is not being saved although it says ``lastmodelobject is saved``.

Comment: why do you have the `if i == 0:` then ? get rid of it. All this code is not executed after the first iteration in the loop due to that check.

Comment: @karthikr ``last_created`` is also the same pattern as the given capricorn here. just the model name is different. i just didnot post that much code

Comment: @karthikr i need to save all 12 model objects in 12 loops. this is why all those ``if i == 0``..., does this make sense? i mean depending on ``i`` i am reading different content from url and saving to different model

Comment: so you are calling this snippet 12 times ? either ways, only the first object is being saved each time. hence the issue. there are work arounds, but this is very inefficient. Example: 12 items, 12 loops is 144 steps for what can be achieved in 12. What are  you trying to achieve? may be there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: @karthikr no, i am calling this snippet only once which however loops 12 times and saves 12 different models depending on ``i``. what would be the efficient way? :(

Comment: you mean further down, there is `i == 1`, `i == 2`, etc.. ?

Comment: @karthikr exactly, i updated my code.

Comment: based on your description, it seems like `last_createdobj` id is 1, which means the rest of the objects are not created. You can always access the shell. `./manage.py shell` and see what objects were actually created.

Comment: @karthikr the thing is, that object with id ``1`` isnot either in db which is reeeeally weird. all other model objects are being created just fine. i am calling the page for this object, i am getting ``LastModelObect matching query does not exist.`` which means it is not in db.

Comment: without the code, could be hard to speculate, but looks like you are doing unnecessary grunt work . Here is a simpler model. https://gist.github.com/karthikbgl/cdbab5b125a434bb90c1#file-sunsigns-py This way, you can debug easily, and code would be at one place.

Comment: @karthikr wow cool, thanks man. Finally learnt new thing today.

Comment: @karthikr honestly, i love your code! this solved my problem. i am falling in love more with django every day.. can you post your answer and i will check it? thnx

Comment: Agreed. Django is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 12 if statements, and 12 different models, I would recommend a change in the models structure. [Something like this](https://gist.github.com/karthikbgl/cdbab5b125a434bb90c1#file-sunsigns-py):

```
#models.py

CAPRICORN = 'Capricorn'
AQUARIUS = 'Aquarius'
PISCES = 'Pisces'
ARIES = 'Aries'
TAURUS = 'Taurus'
GEMINI = 'Gemini'
CANCER = 'Cancer'
LEO = 'Leo'
VIRGO = 'Virgo'
LIBRA = 'Libra'
SCORPIO = 'Scorpio'
SAGITTARIUS  = 'Sagittarius'

SIGN_CHOICES = (
    (1, CAPRICORN,
     2, AQUARIUS,
     3, PISCES,
     4, ARIES,
     5, TAURUS,
     6, GEMINI,
     7, CANCER,
     8, LEO,
     9, VIRGO,
     10, LIBRA,
     11, SCORPIO,
     12, SAGITTARIUS)
  )

class Sign(models.Model):
    signtype = models.CharField(choice=SIGN_CHOICES)
    astro_date = models.DateField() 
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    headcontent = models.TextField()
    rating = RatingField()    
    love_rate = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And in the views, you can just assign the `index+1` to the `signtype` and the `get_or_create` would work fine for you.

Example:

```
astro_date = json_str['daily']['data_date']
sunsign, created = Sign.objects.get_or_create(signtype=index+1, astro_date=astro_date,
                        defaults={
                                  'headline': json_str['daily']['headline'],
                                  'headcontent':json_str['daily']['content'],
                                  'rating':json_str['daily']['rating'],
                                  'love_rate':json_str['daily']['love'],
                        })
```

This way, your code is cleaner, and easier to debug.